Пропуск значений введенных в консоль c помощью модуля node:readline
Необходимо создать массив из значений введенных в консоль. Каждое значение вводится с новой строки, например:
1
2
3
4
5
6

Но после выполнения кода, в массиве data нет первого и последнего значений:
['2', '3', '4', '5']

Код:
import * as readline from 'node:readline/promises';

const data = [];

let rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout,
});

rl.on('line', (line) => {
    data.push(line);
});

rl.on('close', function () {
    console.log(data);
});

await rl.question("Enter numbers: ");

Почему в массив data не попадают значения 1 и 6?

Если после 6 давить "Enter" - она будет в массиве.


Но после выполнения кода, в массиве data нет первого и последнего значений

Твое первое значение "ворует" сам rl.question("Enter numbers: ")...
После последнего так же нужно нажать Enter. Тогда оно будет в массиве.
const readline = require('node:readline/promises')

const data = [];
(async _ => {
    const rl = readline.createInterface({
        input: process.stdin,
        output: process.stdout,
    });

    rl.on('line', line => {
        data.push(line);
    });

    rl.on('close', _ => {
        console.log(data);
    });

    const str = await rl.question("Enter numbers: ");   
    data.push(str);
})()


Спасибо за ответ! С Вашим кодом все значения попадают в ответ, но нарушается порядок введенных данных: первое значение не является первым. В моем случае их количество может доходить до 1000 штук, и это строки текста, их порядок важен для дальнейшей работы. Данные не отсортированы в алфавитном порядке, то есть в дальнейшем нельзя восстановить начальный порядок уже в выходном массиве. Если возможность как то сохранить порядок ввода данных в консоль в массиве data?

@maksssat, я тебе на примере показал ошибочность твоего алгоритма. Ты либо используй question... Либо обрабатывай события.
